# Not able to connect to Spark 1.6.0 from R shell

Tags: r, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, sparklyr

In my environment, I have 2 different versions of Spark (2.2.0 and 1.6.0). I am trying to connect to Spark 1.6.0 from R and I am not able to establish a connection with the guidelines given in the documentation.

I am using:

```
spark_connect(
   master = "yarn-client",  
   config = spark_config(), version = "1.6.0", 
   spark_home = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.1-1.cdh5.12.1.p0.3/lib/spark')
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
Error in force(code) :
  Failed during initialize_connection: Failed to detect version from SPARK_HOME or SPARK_HOME_VERSION. Try passing the spark version explicitly.
Log: /tmp/RtmplCevTH/file1b51126856258_spark.log
```

I am able to connect to Spark 2.2.0 without any problem and am able to query the data as well.

Note sure what I was doing wrong.